# Fazer com que a função addTarefa limpe o inputNovaTarefa deixando o input limpo novamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de entender como a função "limpe" deixando o input vazio.

Segue o código:

```
var inputNovaTarefa = $("#inputNovaTarefa") 
      inputNovaTarefa.html();
      console.log(inputNovaTarefa);
        
      var tarefas= [];

      function addTarefa(){
          inputNovaTarefa.push(tarefas);
          inputNovaTarefa.remove(inputNovaTarefa);
      }

      addTarefa();
```

Obs: Se possível , poderiam me explicar como atribuir o elemento `input` na `var inputNovaTarefa`

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: inputNovaTarefa.val('')